# Can I avoid "white" topBar, when JavaScript is executed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I build my page with `angularJS`. When I test it every thing works well,
but sometimes the page flickers.

Here is a sample when I click `M1 > Sub-Menu-Item`, I see the page flicker.

Can anybody help me, please?

[image]

- My ngRoute:

  ```
  'use strict';
  angular.module('ssdWebClientApp.Routes', [])
      .config(['$routeProvider',
          function($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider
              .when('/m1/', {
                  templateUrl: '/views/m1/m1_list.html',
                  controller: 'M1'
              })

              ...

              .otherwise({
                  redirectTo: '/main'
              });

      }
  ]);
  ```
- My Modules Main.js that enable pushState Featrue:

  ```
  var App = angular.module('ssdWebClientApp', [
          'ngGrid',
          'ngCookies',
          'ngResource',
          'ngRoute',
          'ngAnimate',
          'angular.filter',
          'ssdWebClientApp.Controllers',
          'ssdWebClientApp.Routes',
          'ssdWebClientApp.Services',
          'ssdWebClientApp.Directives'
      ])
          ...
      .config(function($interpolateProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
          $locationProvider.html5Mode({
              enabled: true,
              requireBase: false
          });
          $locationProvider.hashPrefix = '!';
          $httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 300;
      })
          ...
  ```
- My Sub Module Script for M1:

  ```
  'use strict';
  angular.module('ssdWebClientApp.Controllers')
  //s064
  .controller('M1', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$cookies', '$routeParams', '$filter', 'empty', 'm1',
      function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, $cookies, $routeParams, $filter, empty, m1) {
          console.debug('m1 init.');

          $http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;


          // 
          var params = {};
          var sortingBy = ' +' || ' -';
          var inquery_has_been_clicked = false;


          // 
          $scope.inquery = function(reset){
              $scope.hide_grid = false;
              if(reset){
                  $scope.form.offset = 0;
                  params.downloadOrderId = $scope.form.downloadOrderId;
                  params.homeSIMMSISDN = $scope.form.homeSIMMSISDN;
                  params.iccid = $scope.form.iccid;
                  params.msisdn = $scope.form.msisdn;
                  params.limit = $scope.form.limit;
                  params.offset = $scope.form.offset;
              }
              else{
                  params.offset = $scope.form.offset;
                  if(!params.limit){
                      params.limit = $scope.form.limit;
                  }
              }

              // clean data for java server....lol
              if(!params.downloadOrderId) delete params.downloadOrderId;
              if(!params.homeSIMMSISDN) delete params.homeSIMMSISDN;
              if(!params.iccid) delete params.iccid;
              if(!params.msisdn) delete params.msisdn;

              $scope.ajaxing = true;
              m1.m1_downloaded_sim_list(params, function(data, status){
                  if (data.status != 200) {
                      $rootScope.go_error(status, data.error || data.message || data.error_message || data.msg);
                      $scope.customers = [];
                      $scope.total = [];
                      $scope.ajaxing = false;
                      return;
                  };
                  $scope.customers = data.objects;
                  $scope.customers.every(function(row){
                      row.origin_status = row.status;
                      return true;
                  });
                  $scope.total = data.meta.total_count;
                  $scope.ajaxing = false;
              }, function(data, status){
                  $rootScope.go_error(status, data.error || data.message || data.error_message || data.msg);
                  $scope.ajaxing = false;
              });
          };


          //
          $scope.inquery_clicked = function(reset){
              var input_params = [$scope.form.downloadOrderId, $scope.form.homeSIMMSISDN, $scope.form.iccid, $scope.form.msisdn];
              var not_empty_count = 0;
              for(var i = 0; i < input_params.length; i++){
                  if(input_params[i]){
                      not_empty_count += 1;
                  }
              };

              if(not_empty_count >= 2){
                  alert('Please keep only one input');
                  return;
              };

              if($scope.form.downloadOrderId || $scope.form.homeSIMMSISDN || $scope.form.iccid || $scope.form.msisdn){
                  $scope.inquery(reset);
                  inquery_has_been_clicked = true;
              }
              else{
                  alert('No input found.');
              }
          };


          // 
          $scope.show_m1_iccid = function(item){
              // console.log(item);
              var url = item.iccidImage || '';
              // url = CONFIG.file_path + url;
              $('#m1_iccid_bar_code')
                .modal('show')
                .find('.bar_code')
                .attr('src', url);
          };


          // 
          $scope.show_m1_msisdn = function(item){
              // console.log(item);
              var url = item.msisdnImage || '';
              // url = CONFIG.file_path + url;
              $('#m1_msisdn_bar_code')
                .modal('show')
                .find('.bar_code')
                .attr('src', url);
          };


          // 
          $scope.input_security_code = function(item){
              $scope.securityCode = '';
              $scope.prepare_update_record = item;
              $('#input_security_code').modal('show');
          };


          // 
          $scope.update = function(securityCode){
              if(!securityCode){
                  alert("Please input security code.");
                  return;
              }

              var post_data = {
                  imsi: $scope.prepare_update_record.imsi,
                  homeSIMMSISDN: $scope.prepare_update_record.homeSIMMSISDN,
                  securityCode: securityCode,
                  status: $scope.prepare_update_record.status,
              };

              m1.m1_downloaded_sim_update(post_data, function(data, status){
                  if (data.status != 200) {
                      $rootScope.go_error(status, data.error || data.message || data.error_message || data.msg);
                      return;
                  }
                  alert('Update Success!');
                  $('#input_security_code button[data-dismiss=modal]').click();
                  $scope.inquery(false);
              }, function(data, status){
                  $rootScope.go_error(status, data.error || data.message || data.error_message || data.msg);
              });
          };


          // 
          $scope.sorting = function(field){
              if($scope.customers && $scope.customers.length > 0){
                  $scope.customers.sort(function(first ,next){
                      if(sortingBy == ' +'){
                          return first[field] > next[field];
                      }
                      else{
                          return first[field] < next[field];
                      }
                  })
              }

              $('th[field] span.sortingBy').empty();
              $('th[field=' + field + '] span.sortingBy').text(sortingBy);

              if(sortingBy == ' +'){
                  sortingBy = ' -';
              }
              else{
                  sortingBy = ' +';
              }
          };


          // 
          $scope.hide_grid = true;
          $scope.ajaxing = false;
          $scope.prepare_update_record = null;
          $scope.form = {};
          $scope.form.downloadOrderId = $routeParams.downloadOrderId || '';
          $scope.form.homeSIMMSISDN = $routeParams.homeSIMMSISDN || '';
          $scope.form.iccid = $routeParams.iccid || '';
          $scope.form.msisdn = $routeParams.msisdn || '';
          $scope.form.limit = $routeParams.limit || 12;
          $scope.form.offset = $routeParams.offset || 0;
          $scope.total = 0;
          $scope.customers = [];
          $scope.statusList = [];
          $scope.query_string = $scope.form;
          $scope.securityCode = '1';


          // 
          m1.m1_downloaded_sim_status_list(function(data, status){
              if(status != 200){
                  $rootScope.go_error(status, data.error || data.message || data.error_message || data.msg);
                  return;
              }
              $scope.statusList = data.statusList;
          }, function(data, status){
              $rootScope.go_error(status, data.error || data.message || data.error_message || data.msg);
          });


          // 
          $scope.$watch('form.offset', function(new_value, old_value){
              if(inquery_has_been_clicked){
                  $scope.inquery();
              };
          }, true);
      }
  ]);
  ```
- My M1 Feature's View:

  ```
  <div class="container r ssd-platform" style="width: 1300px; min-width: 1300px;">
      <h3 style="text-align: center;">Inquire M1 SIM</h3>

      <br>

      <form role="form" class="form-inline m1">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-voucher">
                  <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
                      <div class="input-group-addon m1_control_panel_label" style="font-size: 10pt;">Voucher No:</div>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="form.downloadOrderId" maxlength="24">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-homesimmsisdn">
                  <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
                      <div class="input-group-addon m1_control_panel_label" style="font-size: 10pt;">Home SIM MSISDN:</div>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="form.homeSIMMSISDN" maxlength="16">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-m1iccid">
                  <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
                      <div class="input-group-addon m1_control_panel_label" style="font-size: 10pt;">M1 ICCID:</div>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="form.iccid" maxlength="20">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 m1-msisdn">
                  <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%;">
                      <div class="input-group-addon m1_control_panel_label" style="font-size: 10pt;">M1 MSISDN:</div>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="form.msisdn" maxlength="16">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 input-group m1-query-btn pull-right" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 100%; height: 40px; border-radius: 0px; height: 38px;" ng-click="inquery_clicked(true);">Inquery</button>
              </div>
          </div>

      </form>

      <div ng-hide="create_paginator(total, form.limit, form.offset).length <= 0" style="position: relative;">
          <ul class="pagination" style="margin: 0px; float: left;" ng-show="create_paginator(total, form.limit, form.offset).length > 0">
              <li><a href ng-click="prev(form);">&laquo;</a></li>
              <li ng-repeat="num in create_paginator(total, form.limit, form.offset)" ng-class="{true: 'active', false: ''}[form.offset/form.limit+1 == num]">
                  <a href ng-click="page(form, num)">{{num}}</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href ng-click="next(form, total)">&raquo;</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <br />

      <table class="table table-bordered no-border-width top-spa" style="width: 100%;">
          <tr>
              <th field="downloadOrderId" style="cursor: pointer; width: 243px;" ng-click="sorting('downloadOrderId')">
                  Voucher No
                  <span class="sortingBy"></span>
              </th>
              <th field="homeSIMMSISDN" style="cursor: pointer; width: 178px;" ng-click="sorting('homeSIMMSISDN')">
                  Home SIM MSISDN
                  <span class="sortingBy"></span>
              </th>
              <th field="iccid" style="cursor: pointer; width: 190px;" ng-click="sorting('iccid')">
                  M1 ICCID
                  <span class="sortingBy"></span>
              </th>
              <th field="imsi" style="cursor: pointer; width: 200px;" ng-click="sorting('imsi')">
                  M1 IMSI
                  <span class="sortingBy"></span>
              </th>
              <th field="msisdn" style="cursor: pointer; width: 200px;" ng-click="sorting('msisdn')">
                  M1 MSISDN
                  <span class="sortingBy"></span>
              </th>
              <th field="status" style="cursor: pointer; width: 135px;" ng-click="sorting('status')">
                  Status
                  <span class="sortingBy"></span>
              </th>
              <th style="width: 108px;">
                  Action
              </th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in customers" ng-if="customers.length > 0 && ajaxing == false && !hide_grid">
              <td style="text-align: center;">{{ item.downloadOrderId }}</td>
              <td style="text-align: left;">{{ item.homeSIMMSISDN }}</td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <a ng-click="show_m1_iccid(item);">
                      {{ item.iccid }}
                  </a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">{{ item.imsi }}</td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <a ng-click="show_m1_msisdn(item);">
                      {{ item.msisdn }}
                  </a>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <select class="form-control" ng-model="item.status" style="padding: 0px; width: 110px!important;" ng-disabled="item.origin_status == 'Reject' || item.origin_status == 'Collected'">
                      <option ng-repeat="status in statusList" value="{{ status }}" ng-selected="item.status == status">{{ status }}</option>
                  </select>
              </td>
              <td style="text-align: center;">
                  <button
                      type="button"
                      class="btn btn-default btn-lg"
                      style="border-radius: 0px; width: 100%; height: 25px; padding: 0px;"
                      ng-click="input_security_code(item)"
                      ng-disabled="item.status == 'Booking' || item.origin_status == 'Reject' || item.origin_status == 'Collected'">
                      Update
                  </button>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-show="customers.length == 0 && ajaxing == false && !hide_grid">
              <td colspan="7">
                  <div style="width: 100%; background-color: transparent; text-align: center; color: red;">
                      No Data Found.
                  </div>        
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-show="ajaxing == true && !hide_grid">
              <td colspan="7">
                  <div class="ajaxing-min" style="min-height: 30px; width: 100%;"></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="m1_iccid_bar_code" style="z-index:9999;">
          <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 800px; margin-top: 200px;">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header bg-primary" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                              <h3 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel" style="color: white;">M1 ICCID Bar Code</h3>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
                      <img class="bar_code" src="/images/glyphicons-halflings.png" alt="bar_code">
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" style="margin-left: 40%; margin-right: 40%; width: 20%; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; border-radius: 0px; height: 25px;" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal fade" id="m1_msisdn_bar_code" style="z-index:9999;">
          <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 800px; margin-top: 200px;">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header bg-primary" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                              <h3 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel" style="color: white;">M1 MSISDN Bar Code</h3>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
                      <img class="bar_code" src="/images/glyphicons-halflings.png" alt="bar_code">
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" style="margin-left: 40%; margin-right: 40%; width: 20%; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; border-radius: 0px; height: 25px;" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal fade" id="input_security_code" style="z-index:9999;">
          <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 600; margin-top: 200px;">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header bg-primary" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-8">
                              <h3 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel" style="color: white;">Input Security Code</h3>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body" style="text-align: center;">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Security Code" ng-model="securityCode" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <div class="btn-group-lg top-spa" style="text-align: center;">
                          <button type="button" style="width: 20%; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; border-radius: 0px; height: 25px;" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="update(securityCode);">OK</button>
                          <button type="button" style="width: 20%; padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; border-radius: 0px; height: 25px;" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Counter -->
  <style>
      form.m1 div[class^=col-md] {
          font-size: 8pt;
          padding: 0px;
          padding-left: 5px;
          font-weight: bold;
      }

      .ajaxing-min {
          background-image: url('/images/ajaxing-min.gif');
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: center;
      }

      .col-voucher {
          width: 27%;
      }

      .m1-query-btn, .col-voucher {
          padding-left: 0px!important;
      }

      .col-homesimmsisdn {
          width: 25%;
      }

      .col-m1iccid {
          width: 25%;
      }

      .m1-msisdn {
          width: 23%;
      }

      .m1-query-btn {
          width: 200px;
          float: right;
      }

      th {
          background-color: lightgrey;
          text-align: center;
      }
  </style>
  ```
- My index.html

  ```
  <!doctype html>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>GreenRoam</title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

      <!-- build:css /styles/app.css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/jqueryui-timepicker-addon/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/swipebox/src/css/swipebox.css">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/jquery-resizable-columns/dist/jquery.resizableColumns.css"> -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/ng-grid/ng-grid.min.css"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/ssd-platform.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/ssd-platform-ng-grid-extends.css">
      <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ssdWebClientApp">

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="{% get_static_prefix %}components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
  <script src="{% get_static_prefix %}components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

  <!-- Header - NaviBar -->
  <ssd-navbar></ssd-navbar>

  <!-- Render Part -->
  <div ng-view></div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <ssd-footer></ssd-footer>

  <!-- Additional Template -->
  <ssd-alert></ssd-alert>

  <!-- build:js /scripts/app.js -->
  <script src="/components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/jqueryui-timepicker-addon/dist/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/jqueryui-timepicker-addon/dist/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/swipebox/src/js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/angular/angular.js"></script>

  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/affix.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/alert.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/button.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/carousel.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/collapse.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/modal.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/tab.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/transition.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/bootstrap/js/popover.js"></script>

  <script src="/components/smoothscroll-for-websites/SmoothScroll.js"></script>

  <script src="/components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/angular-filter/dist/angular-filter.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/ng-grid/build/ng-grid.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/ng-grid/plugins/ng-grid-flexible-height.js"></script>
  <script src="/components/ng-grid/plugins/ng-grid-layout.js"></script>

  <!-- Base -->
  <script src="/scripts/Config/config.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/Config/base_config.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/Config/code_config.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/Modules/main.js"></script>

  <!-- Routes -->
  <script src="/scripts/Routes/routes.js"></script>

  <!-- Services -->
  <script src="/scripts/Services/services.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/Modules/product/services.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/Modules/customer/faq/services.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/Modules/product/onstore_management/services.js"></script>

  <!-- Directives -->
  <script src="/scripts/Directives/directives.js"></script>

  <!-- Modules -->
      ...
  <script src="/scripts/Modules/m1/m1.js"></script>
      ...

  <!-- Main -->
  <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->

          <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
          <script>
              (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
              })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

              ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
              ga('send', 'pageview');
          </script>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: Use routes (`ngRoute` or `ui.router`) so only the content view is updated instead of your entire page

Comment: Showing us your code might help.

Comment: do you mean the space between the drop down element and the top navigation? or the flickering white top after selection?

Comment: Add some sample code on how your views are structured. That might help in suggesting a solution.

Comment: I think that maybe it's caused by my browser which executes/runs JavaScript' script too slow? I want my page switch smoothly without any page broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I hava solved this problem, the top-bar-space in the moment cause by 
CSS Style

```
style="width: 100%!important; position: fixed;"
```

or

```
style="position: fixed!important; width: 100%!important; top: 0px!important;"
```

After I remove it, It's work well. But I don't know why...